# Get current URL and update parameters in URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

Thank you for your time in advance.

I am trying to get the value from the URL and auto-fill a radio option.

Example URL = https://example.com/v2-search/?&orderBy=relevance&tags=Kinship

```html
<form action="https://example.com/v2-search/?" method="GET" >
    <div class="uk-inline">
        
        <div class="uk-inline">

           <label>Filter by: <label> 
           <input id="distance" class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="orderBy" value="distance"> Distance 
            <input id="relevance" class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="orderBy" value="relevance" > Relevance 

        </div>
        
        <div class="uk-inline">
        <button style="margin-left: 15px;" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small uk-mobile-width">Update</button>
    </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

Here is the JS I am using with comments.

```js
function autoFill() {
  var ob = url.searchParams.get("orderBy"); //Getting the value from the URL for the first radio options selected.
  var radioElements = document.getElementsByName("orderBy"); //Selecting the first radio options.

  for (var i=0; i<radioElements.length; i++) {
    if (radioElements[i].getAttribute('value') == 'ob') {
      radioElements[i].checked = true; //Adding checked to the value based on the URL
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the URL query (search) string into a [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instance which makes getting values easier.

You can then search for the relevant radio button and check it if found

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
const orderBy = params.get("orderBy")

const radio = document.querySelector(`input[name="orderby"][value="${orderBy}"]`)
if (radio) {
  radio.checked = true
}
```